# What does Trace Enable mean in Lauterbach?

Tags: emulation, trace, lauterbach, asic

I am working on Lauterbach to collect the traces from a sink where a processor is a source.
This is done using a 'step' operation and while doing so, in the midway on the trace.list window I am displayed with 'TRACE ENABLE' in red (as attached in the image).

My question is, what does this mean? what does the TRACE ENABLE indicate?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.[image: trace_enable]

Comment: Which Trace.METHOD have you choose in the window Trace.state?

Comment: @Holger it is the trace.ONCHIP(collecting it from the ETF memory via Jtag)